# dplyr::filter criteria from other data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to filter a df1 with criteria of df2 and count the rows of df1 which fullfill the criteria of df2.

```
df1<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4),
                B=c(1,2,3,4))
df2<-data.frame(A_min=c(2,3),
                A_max=c(3,3))

df2<-df2%>%
  mutate(Score=df1%>%
           filter(between(df1$A,df2$A_min,df2$A_max))%>%
           norw())
```

I get this error:

> Error in mutate(): ! Problem while computing Score = df1 %>% filter(between(df1$A, df2$A_min,   df2$A_max)). Caused by error in
> filter(): ! Problem while computing ..1 = between(df1$A, df2$A_min,
> df2$A_max)`. Caused by error in between(): ! left must be length
> 1

I can understand the error message, but I cannot find a way of handling it.
Outcome shoud look like:

```
  A_min A_max Score
1     2     3     2
2     3     3     1
```

Comment: Why not just `df2$A_max - df2$A_min + 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map2` from `purrr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df2 |>
  mutate(Score = map2(A_min, A_max, ~ nrow(filter(df1, between(A, .x, .y)))))
```

Or `rowwise()`:

```r
df2 |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(Score = nrow(filter(df1, between(A, A_min, A_max)))) |>
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```r
  A_min A_max Score
1     2     3     2
2     3     3     1
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake, had an error in the code and forgot the .x and .y argument. Seems to work now, Thanks!

Comment: but maybe another question: how can I add more criteria to the map2 function?

Comment: What kinds? What would be the goal? (It might need a new question though).

Comment: for example multiple ranges I want to filter at the same time. e.g. B_min and B_max. doing it by %>% map2() %>% map2()..... seems wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your error is separate from anything to do with the second data frame:

```
df1<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4),
                B=c(1,2,3,4))
df1 %>% filter(between(df1$A,df2$A_min,df2$A_max))
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = between(df1$A,
  df2$A_min, df2$A_max)`.
Caused by error in `between()`:
! `left` must be length 1
```

You can't pass vectors over length 1 to the left and right values for `between`. This is what is causing your error. Try instead:

```
df1 %>% filter(df1$A >= df2$A_max & df2$A_min <= df2$A_max)
  A B
1 3 3
2 4 4
```