# dplyr::filter multiple criteria from other data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

Refering on this topic:

[dplyr::filter criteria from other data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73122297/dplyrfilter-criteria-from-other-data-frame)

I adjusted the df to fit better to my complex df.

```
df1<-data.frame(A=c(1:10),
                B=c(3:12))
df2<-data.frame(A_min=c(2,3),
                A_max=c(3,3),
                B_min=c(1,2),
                B_max=c(2,2))
```

I was not able to put multiple criteria in the code with dplyr::map2

```
df2 |>
  mutate(Score = map2(A_min, A_max, ~ nrow(filter(df1, between(A, .x, .y)))))
```

I needed to adjust the code so it works in my case (don´t know exactly why between is not working).

```
mutate(Score=map2_dbl(A_min,A_max,~nrow(filter(df1,A>=.x & A<=.y))))
```

How can I add a second criteria e.g. B_min and B_max to filter at the same time to get a combined score with both criteria?  (Edited the question to make it clear what the goal is).

Comment: It is working fine for me.  Can you show your output

Comment: Sorry for the change in last minute, had to edit the question beacuse I had an mistake in my code.... but main question is left: how can I add multiple criteria to the filter step?

Comment: Does the `pmap` in the solution helps? Or are you looking for a more general solution?

Comment: Thanks for the solution @akrun but I need a single score for both criteria. I want to filter df1 with the criteria for A and for B giving a combined score. I know the example df´s are not good showing the problem ....

Comment: I got it! With your code I can just add and "&" and it works fine now. I guess it was not working for me since I did not use the across(everything()). Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `pmap`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
 df2 |>
  mutate(Score = pmap(across(everything()), 
  ~ tibble(A= nrow(filter(df1, between(A, ..1, ..2))), 
   B= nrow(filter(df1, between(B, ..3, ..4)))))) %>%
   unnest_wider(Score, names_sep = "")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 6
  A_min A_max B_min B_max ScoreA ScoreB
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>  <int>
1     2     3     1     2      2      0
2     3     3     2     2      1      0
```

---

Or if there are multiple sets of columns, reshape to 'long' format before doing the processing and then reshape it back to 'wide' format

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c("name",  ".value"), 
      names_sep = "_") %>%
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(name, Score = df1 %>% 
   filter(between(cur_data()[[name]], min, max)) %>%
     nrow, .keep = 'unused') %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = Score, 
    names_glue = "Score{name}") %>% 
   select(-rn) %>% 
   bind_cols(df2, .)
   A_min A_max B_min B_max ScoreA ScoreB
1     2     3     1     2      2      0
2     3     3     2     2      1      0
```